# How to create random function in Microsoft VS

Tags: c++

I'm very new in Visual Studio so I dont know how to make a random function. I've been using Borland all the time. In borland it works well this method:

```
randomize();
int n=random(10);
```

Visual Studio gives me error using randomize function, I tried using `rand();` like this:

```
rand();
int n=random(10);
```

It isn't working, anyone can help me? ( I tried to find this problem here in stackoverflow and didn't get the solution, I don't think this is duplicated)

Comment: Have you attempted to search for rand() examples?

Comment: Why not use standard C++ functions.

Comment: I'm trying using standard c++ functions, but I want to learn new ways like I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the standard library you can do something like this:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Mersenne Twister Pseudo Random Generator
    std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};

    // Random number range (inclusive)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> pick{0, 9};

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << pick(gen) << ' ';
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 7 0 2 1 2 6 9 8 1
```